# How to sample cell from one of two columns?

Tags: r

I would like to define a new.column in my dataframe. The new.column takes a value from one of two other columns. A given cell of the new.column should only sample cells from the other columns if these are in the same row.

What I want:

```
first.column second.column new.column
---------------------------------------
a b a
c d d
```

Here, we are sampling `first.column` and `second.column` to define the new column. We randomly picked `a` from the first row and `d` from the second row.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
set.seed(1)
first = sample(c('a', 'c'), 2)
second = sample(c('b', 'd'), 2)
my.tibble = tibble(first, second)

my.tibble = my.tibble %>% 
  mutate(
    third = sample(c(first, second), 1)
  )

my.tibble
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# first second third
# <chr> <chr>  <chr>
# 1 a     b      b    
# 2 c     d      b
```

It looks like I sampled the second row twice.

Comment: You have to use `rowwise` in order to let the process know that you want to sample from each row separately. Try this: `my.tibble %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(third = sample(c(first, second), 1)) %>%
  ungroup()`

Comment: Use base R. `cbind(my.tibble, third=apply(my.tibble, MARGIN=1, sample, size=1))`. BTW, using `set.seed()`, e.g. `set.seed(1)` makes your `sample`ing reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `sample` rowwise and attribute the result to a new column

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "b", "c"), col2 = c("r", "t", "i"), col3 = c("w", "j", "d"))
within(df, newcol <- apply(df, 1, sample, 1))
#  col1 col2 col3 newcol
#1    a    r    w      a
#2    b    t    j      t
#3    c    i    d      d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with `tidyverse` we can use `map2_chr` if you have two columns

```
library(tidyverse)
my.tibble %>%  mutate(third = map2_chr(first, second, ~sample(c(.x, .y), 1)))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  first second third
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1   a     d      a    
#2   c     b      c
```

Or more generally for many columns use `pmap_chr`

```
my.tibble %>%  mutate(third = pmap_chr(., ~sample(c(...), 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` with `Map`

```
my.tibble$third <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) sample(c(x, y), 1), 
         my.tibble$first, my.tibble$second))
```